# Socket error 10053 software caused connection abort

Tags: sockets, delphi, ftp

I have a application which will receive files from FTP and uploaded in to Mainframe server. 
I am getting a "Socket error 10053 software caused connection abort" when I assign

FTPTransfertype = ftASCII

If I change this to FtBinary I'm not getting this error but data not uploaded properly in this mode.

I am getting this error only in application server (Production server) not in the development server (here I faced this issue only once in the  FTPTransfertype = ftASCII assignment)

I have changed the FTP connectivity mode to Passive but its not working..

Please help me on this.

Comment: A more precise description of the problem than "data not uploaded properly" would be helpful. What is wrong with the data?

Comment: Thanks David, this issue have been corrected by enabling FTP error log.. and the problem was on the FTP server side.

Answer (score 2):

I recomment to see **Microsoft Windows Socket Errors**  page:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668(v=vs.85).aspx

In your case:

> Software caused connection abort. An established connection was
>   aborted by the software in your host computer, possibly due to a data
>   transmission time-out or protocol error.